# How to prove that "If $A$ $\subseteq N$ is the domain of psudodefined recursive function then it is the range of a primitive recursive function"

Tags: logic

Does anybody know how to prove the statement "If $A$ $\subseteq N$ is the domain of psudodefined recursive function then it is the range of a primitive recursive function"

I've found this: http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~jean/old511/html/cis51108sl11.pdf

thou it does not seem to be it.

Comment: I think I know how to prove it, but without knowing what your thoughts have been I don't know how to lead you towards figuring it out. It would also help if you gave the definitions your course/book is using, but your thoughts are even more important.

Comment: Please could you say what is meant by a 'pseudodefined recursive function'?

Comment: @MarkWildon actually I don't know, I'm translating it, it could mean pseudo specific or pseudo distinct. hope it helps

Comment: @MarkS. my book is not in English, so it is hard to give the definitions. my thoughts are also no more than the stuff in the PDF. I've been trying to modify the proof there. thou at this point I myself don't understand what is mean by pseudo define. hope somebody can figure it out, if not I will ask my teacher tomorrow.

Comment: It seems possible that it means "the domain of a partial recursive function" - that makes the theorem correct, at least.  What language is the original in? There may well be people here who speak the language.